# Python: Custom class to work with nested defaultdict

Tags: python, defaultdict, shallow-copy

Hello I have these two classes

```
class BaseCounter(object): 
  def __init__(self):
    print ("BaseCounter init = ")
    self._counter = 0

  def increment(self, count=1):       
    self._counter += count

  def items(self):
    return self._counter


class DictCounter(object):
  def __init__(self, dict_class):
    self._counter = defaultdict(lambda: dict_class)

  def increment(self, key, value, *args, **kwargs):
    print (key, value, args, kwargs)
    self._counter[key].increment(value, *args, **kwargs)

  def items(self):
    result = []
    for key, counter in self._counter.items():
        result.append((key, counter.items()))
    return result
```

and I am trying to create something like this:

```
y = DictCounter(DictCounter(DictCounter(BaseCounter())))
y.increment(10,1,2,3)
y.increment(10,1,2,3)
y.increment(10,1,3,3)
y.increment(10,2,2,3)
```

which leads to

```
10 1 2 12
10 1 3 12
10 2 2 12
10 2 3 12
```

but I was expecting

```
10 1 2 6
10 1 3 3
10 2 2 3
```

it should simulate, which is working correctly

```
defaultdict(defaultdict(defaultdict(int))) "with counter at the end"
```

but I am confused with the behavior (I think there will be problem with shallow copy or something with references)

Any idea?

Comment: All relevant code, as a [mcve], must be part of the question here, not from a link, sorry.

Comment: You are not creating new classes; your `lambda: dict_class` returns the same instance created at the start. So all your keys in the `defaultdict` all reference a *single object*.

Comment: You'll need to pass in actual factories: `DictCounter(lambda: DictCounter(lambda: DictCounter(lambda: BaseCounter())))`, and use those as the `defaultdict()` factory (drop the `lambda in the `__init__` method).

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right I changed it and it works but ... after 2 minutes .. I get it :D Try to paraphrase you - It was because I passed object in constructor and then if there was new key the same object was used (reference to same place in memory), right?

Comment: Exactly, you just shared references to a single object, not new instances or copies.

Answer (score 0):

As Martijn Pieters said. The problem was referencing to the same object (dict_class) for every new key. So instead of this:

```
class DictCounter(object):
   def __init__(self, dict_class):
      self._counter = defaultdict(lambda: dict_class)

 ....

DictCounter(DictCounter(DictCounter(BaseCounter())))
```

do this:

```
class DictCounter(object):
   def __init__(self, dict_class):
      self._counter = defaultdict(dict_class)

 ....

DictCounter(lambda: DictCounter(lambda: DictCounter(lambda: BaseCounter())))
```

I was trying to describe it a little bit more at [my blog](https://petrlorenc.github.io/Python-defaultdict/).